# How to corrupt WMI

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

There is a lot of articles about how to fix a corrupt WMI, but nothing about how to make it corrupt. I would like to destroy it to test a PS script, which could fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by corrupt WMI? Windows Management Instrumentation consists of a set of extensions to the Windows Driver Model that provides an operating system interface through which instrumented components provide information and notification. If you want to test your script then try a class which doesn't exist.

Comment: Post your code how you are testing and doing the fix part

Comment: This blog has a number of "fix it" steps and the repository location: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository/.  You should do this on a throw-away environment as the recovery may not be complete.

Comment: @RanadipDutta : Sorry, question is related to WMI repository.

Comment: Wmi repository can be corrupted in a number of ways like deleting or renaming a class, deleting or renaming a namespace, deleting instances of static classes etc. Unfortunatelly these can be performed easilly using wmi tester, powershell, wmic, vbscript...